# Using COUNTIFS to count times within next 6 hours, next 12 hours, etc

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2016, countif

I currently have COUNTIFS set up to count times in specific 6 hour time frames, for instance 12:00-18:00, but would like to change it to 6 hour increments FROM the CURRENT time: 6, 12, 18, and 24.

The database it is pulling the information from is in the following format, preceded by the date: `12/19/2018  21:00:00`

My current working formula is this: `=COUNTIFS($B:$B,">=6:00",$B:$B,"<11:59")`

*I would like to NOT include timeframes like both `12/19/2018 21:00` and `12/20/2018 21:00` in the same range as they are a day apart.

Comment: I have tried `=COUNTIFS($B:$B,">="NOW(),$B:$B,"<"NOW()+TIME(6,0,0))` to no avail.

Comment: Try =COUNTIFS(B:B,">="&NOW(),B:B,"<="&(NOW()+(6/24))) and let me know if it works

Comment: So it looks like that formula works, but it's adding them all together as it goes when I change the 6 to 12, 16, 24. I guess I could fix that buy adding a bit to subtract the previous 6 hours.

Comment: Sorry, I realized I was supposed to change the first NOW instance and now it seems to be working! Gonna test it out further. Thank you!

Comment: @MathewBauler,, to make the Formula Dynamic instead of `Time Value` or Function  `Now ()`,, you many use `2 Cell references as Criteria`, would much better and a Clean method. ☺